# How can I build an SDK for a Android app in .net Maui

Tags: android, .net, mobile, sdk, maui

I have a task that is to creating some sort of SDK to allow new developers to add custom Widgets to our .net Maui Android app. These widgets is how some sensors will be displayed in our gadget. I'll explaing better:

We have a standard weather widget that is only a cloud with the temperature, a dev could build a animated widget like a cloud with a thunder for instance.

The question is how could he do some upload or update right into his app in his smartphone, should we build a companion app or website in which he could update the smartphone app with an upload, or can we upload in runtime with ADB.

I'm new to mobile development and I am kind of lost in this, so I appreciate if you could give me some ideas or directions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've been developing apps for years, but I would not attempt to do this on a mobile device. For security and privacy, everything is "locked down". Apple and Google have worked hard to make it difficult to alter an existing app, except via the original publisher publishing an updated version of the app. You are in "research" territory here. Beyond the scope of StackOverflow, sorry. SO is intended to help resolve specific, concrete, obstacles that you encounter. AFTER researching, finding a promising approach, writing code.